# What should I use to add 20% noise to my test data

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I want to add 20% noise to my test data and I'm torn on how to do it, because I don't know how the `np.random` function actually works.

Should I use something like that:

```
x_test_noise = x_test * np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2, size=x_test.shape)
```

or something like that:

```
x_test_noise=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range (len(x_test)):
    for j in range(len(x_test.columns)):
        x_test_noise=x_test*np.random.uniform(0.8,1.2)
```

My main concern is that I want every value of x_test to be multiplied by a **different** value drawn from the random distribution. Is the first syntax going to do that or is it going to multiply every value of x_test with the same value drawn from the random distribution?

Comment: The first syntax is what you should do. It will multiply each value by a different random factor between 0.8 and 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

Your first code is doing what you expect in an efficient (vectorial) way: it will multiply each value by a different random factor between 0.8 and 1.2.

To convince yourself, just design a small graphical example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 100

x_test = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 5, N))
noise = np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2, size=x_test.shape)

x_test_noise = x_test * noise

df = pd.DataFrame({'real': x_test, 'noise': noise, 'real*noise': x_test_noise})
df.plot()

# add lower/upper bounds
df['real'].mul(0.8).plot(ls=':', color='k')
df['real'].mul(1.2).plot(ls=':', color='k')
```

Output:

[image]

---

##### plotting code without [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) dependency

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 100

x_test = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 5, N))
noise = np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2, size=x_test.shape)

x_test_noise = x_test * noise

ax = plt.subplot()

ax.plot(x_test, label='real')
ax.plot(noise, label='noise')
ax.plot(x_test_noise, label='real*noise')
ax.plot(x_test*0.8, ls=':', color='k')
ax.plot(x_test*1.2, ls=':', color='k')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Your answer looks good and I have already upvoted it, but I never use Pandas and there seems to be a step missing that actually causes the plot to show up on the screen? I have used matplotlib.pyplot before and I use a `plt.show()` for that, but your code doesn't even have a `plt` to show. Thank you.

Comment: @Mark I used pandas to plot ([`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which loads matplotlib (by default) in the background). You just need to have matplotlib installed and to `import pandas as pd` and the above snippet should work fine. I added another code that doesn't require pandas/

Comment: Thank you for the non-Pandas answer... I actually liked your answer for the simplicity of the Pandas solution!!! I experimented some more (on macOS) and, using your original Pandas code, I need to add an extra last line `plt.show()` after `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` then it all works fine. ‍♂️

Comment: @Mark maybe you used a shell? In a jupyter notebook, the display is on by default without requiring to explicitly run `plt.show()` ([read more](/questions/54422714/when-is-plt-show-required-to-show-a-plot-and-when-is-it-not)) ;)

Comment: Aha! Thank you. I am just using a shell... I'm not a real Jupyterlab-using Data Scientist :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a different between using:
x_test_noise=x_test*np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2, size=x_test.shape
and 
x_test_noise=x_test*np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2)  ?

Thanks again in advance!